# Select box select item from model in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given this code in controller:

```
  $scope.selectedParam = 95
  $scope.param = {
    value: {
      95: "John",
      193: "Doe",
    }
  }
```

And such a template

```
  <select 
      ng-model="selectedParam"                 
      ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in param.value track by key">
</select>
```

How do I make item from model to be selected?

Here is the example on **[jsfiddle that is not working](http://jsfiddle.net/b247znjw/1/)**
and here is **[one that work](http://jsfiddle.net/SET001/9vL4u7v7/1/)**.

Why first example does not work. Are there any ways to make it work? I need digits to be keys of the options object, not the values. Otherwise I would need to refactor tonnes of code in my application.

Comment: which fiddle is working? both works as same

Comment: @azad on first fiddle nothing is selected in selectbox which is wrong. On second fiddle `John` item is selected, which is what I want.

Comment: use string as key `95` => `"95"`

Comment: Do you need the `selectedParam` to be the key too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using integers as JSON-keys, JSON mandates that all keys must be strings. Then if you remove the track by you can see it working again.
Html:

```
<select 
   ng-model="selectedParam"                 
   ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in param.value"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.selectedParam = "95"
  $scope.param = {
    value: {
    "95": "John",
    "193": "Doe",
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bfryxsxo/

Comment: Also note `trackexpr` is used when working with an array of objects not with object properties

Comment: assuming that I can't know beforehand the type of value, I I think I should make changes in `param` structure so that `values would be plain array with pairs `key` and `value`...

Answer (score -1):

Just change "selectedParam" to string type instead of integer as follows:-

Controller

```
$scope.selectedParam = "95";
```

In View

```
<select ng-model="selectedParam">
     <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in param.value track by key" value="{{key}}">{{ value}}</option>
</select>
```

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('defaultValueSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.selectedParam = "95";
  $scope.param = {
    value: {
      95: "John",
      193: "Doe",
    }
  }
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="defaultValueSelect">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <form name="myForm">         
            <select ng-model="selectedParam">
                <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in param.value track by key" value="{{key}}">{{ value}}</option>
            </select>
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't make a ng-repeat for ng-options unless you really have a specific reason why it is necessary. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#choosing-between-ngrepeat-and-ngoptions-

Comment: @jlast Thanks for sharing this valuable information, appreciate it.